# What is the meaning of SI unit $Ns$ (NEWTON.TIME)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, si-units

for ex: when i say newton per meter it mean that 1 newton is applied per 1 meter.
but what i mean by saying N.s (s=time in sec) i.e Impulse or momentum. N.s does not mean that certain force is being applied on a body for a particular time as 
suppose 
if i have 40 Ns(s=sec)
what it mean?
does it mean that 40 newton is applied for 1 sec 
but i can't say this because if it comes from 20*2 (20 N * 2 sec) it will also give 40Ns.

Comment: A newton-second is a unit of momentum. It makes sense to express it that way because force is the rate of change of momentum, $F = \mathrm{d}p/\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: my friend i know its momentum .
i want to know the meaning of Ns(N=newton s=sec)
as we know the meaning of N/s.

Comment: then I'm afraid that I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

$N.s$ is the unit of Momentum and Impulse.
Let's consider, what the quantities itself are so that you might be able to correlate them with their units.
Speaking colloquially, Momentum is a measure of strength and a measure of how difficult it is to stop an object, and Impulse is the measure of how much the force $changes$ the momentum of that object.

$Force$ $applied$ $over$ $time$ $periods$ $create$ $impulses$.

Another way of describing it or expanding on the above is, Impulse could be a measure of how the force $changes$ over the $period$ $of$ $time$ and henceforth causing a change in momentum. So if, impulse itself is a quantity that relates the sum of changes caused by the force in the momentum or the period of time, this quantity could be accurately represented by $N.s$

So consider the impulse is, say, $40 N.s.$, we mean that over a period of time the average force of $40N$ caused a change in momentum equating to $40N.s$

Finally,
$$J=\int Fdt$$

Hope it answers your question!

Comment: <B>how do we know what period of time the force is being appleid.</B>

Comment: It's not possible to know if any other parameters are not given. It's like asking, what's the acceleration if force is 40N, and no other parameter is given. To comment precisely, we need to have other relevant parameters.

Comment: **basically i'm asking the difference b/w   N/s and N.s**

Comment: They're fundamentally different quantities, describing two different things, as I've explained above.

Answer (score 0):

A force is applied for a certain time.

Comment: This might be better if you expanded a bit more on this short sentence.